# Code to convert .xls to .xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code snippet online to convert my `.xls` files to `.xlsx` files.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname, SaveFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Pathname = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    wb.CheckCompatibility = True
    saveFileName = Replace(Filename, ".xls", ".xlsx")

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFileName

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

When I run this it does create the back-up properly but when it comes to saving the file it displays the message that test.xls already exists in the folder, but I want it to be saved as .xlsx, as seen in the replace function.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Instead of doing a Find/Replace on the path, does `wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` work?  Or a combination of the two maybe?

Comment: @Soulfire I've tried both and only the fileformat function, but I still get the same message

Comment: For newer people, this does output the new files into your Documents folder on windows, NOT the folder with the original files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFileName
```

with

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

and replace

```
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

with

```
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```